# std::construct_at which default initializes?

Tags: c++, c++20

[`std::construct_at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/construct_at) is equivalent to

```
template<class T, class... Args>
constexpr T* construct_at( T* p, Args&&... args ) {
    return ::new (const_cast<void*>(static_cast<const volatile void*>(p)))
        T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

except that `construct_at` may be used in evaluation of constant expressions.

As you can see, if no `args` are given, it will value initialize the object. Is there a way to achieve default initialization? To call the equivalent of `::new (p) T;` (note the lack of parenthesis).

In other words, is it possible to execute default initialization with placement new which can be used in constant expressions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In other words, is it possible to execute default initialization with placement new which can be used in constant expressions?

No, not without further language support. This is why [P2283](https://wg21.link/p2283) proposes adding `default_construct_at` to be a magic library function that lets you do this.

Comment: Interesting note: The standard allocator construct methods also have the same limitation.  This is why my [small_vector](https://github.com/Ambeco/mpd/blob/master/SmallContainers/small_vector.hpp) implementation has constructor and resize overloads that take a custom `default_not_value_construct` value :(

Comment: If you have any influence on choosing between the alternatives, maybe `std::default_construct_tag` is better, because it'd enable having things like `push_back(std::default_construct_tag{});`, in other words, adding default initialized elements to a container (or resizing with default initialized elements, such things).

Comment: I wonder whether `default_construct_at` could or should be defined in terms of `start_lifetime_as`?

Comment: @sandthorn No definitely not - `default_construct_at` needs to invoke the default constructor (which might do work). `start_lifetime_as` doesn't call a constructor or run any code - it's just a signal that there is now an object here.